# pip is not installing my data_files. But easy_install does

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, setup.py

This is going to be a short question.

The source is here: https://github.com/exhuma/grc

And the title explains my problem ;)

I registered and uploaded the package to `pypi`. Now if I run `easy_install grc`, it works as expected. But if I run `pip install grc`, it installs properly, but does not install the data_files. I don't see why this is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the files aren't installed in the path you expect. In Ubuntu 11.10, I see them under `/usr/local/configs` as it can be seen in `pip uninstall` output:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall grc
Uninstalling grc:
  /usr/local/bin/grc
  /usr/local/configs/apache_access.yml
  /usr/local/configs/aptitude.yml
  /usr/local/configs/pysetup.yml
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grc
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grc-1.0b3.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)?
```

In your system, I guess you can check also the output of `pip uninstall` to make sure.

Comment: ouch... if that's the case I messed up. That's not where they were supposed to go.  I'll check later today and let you know.

Comment: I think [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5423147/183066) should be useful to your problem.

Comment: Okay thanks. It worked. I did not see that ``pip`` installed the files elsewhere. I now updated the source and ditched ``easy_install`` :)