# include extra file in a Python package using setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I am attempting to build a python wheel using `setuptools`. The package needs to include two files:

- `mymodule.py` - a python module in the same directory as `setup.py`
- `myjar.jar` - a java .jar file that exists outside of my package directory

I am building my package using `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel`.

If I call `setup()` like so:

```
setup(
    name="mypkg",
    py_modules=["mymodule"],
    data_files=[('jars', ['../target/scala-2.11/myjar.jar'])]
)
```

then `myjar.jar` does successfully get included in the .whl (good so far) however when I `pip install mypkg` it places the jar at `/usr/local/myjar.jar` ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8471657/201657) kinda explains why) which isn't what I want at all, I want it to exist in the same place as `mymodule.py`, i.e. `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`

If I change `setup.py` to

```
setup(
    name="mypkg",
    py_modules=["mymodule"],
    package_data={'jars': '../target/scala-2.11/myjar.jar'}
)
```

or

```
setup(
    name="mypkg",
    py_modules=["mymodule"],
    package_data={'jars': ['../target/scala-2.11/myjar.jar']}
)
```

then `myjar.jar` simply doesn't get included in the .whl. I tried copying `myjar.jar` into the same directory and changing `setup.py` to:

```
setup(
    name="mypkg",
    py_modules=["mymodule"],
    package_data={'jars': 'myjar.jar'}
)
```

or

```
setup(
    name="mypkg",
    py_modules=["mymodule"],
    package_data={'jars': ['myjar.jar']}
)
```

but still `myjar.jar` does not get included in the .whl.

I've been tearing my hair out over this for hours, hence why I'm here.

I've read a myriad of SO posts on this:

- [How to include package data with setuptools/distribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute)
- [MANIFEST.in ignored on "python setup.py install" - no data files installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596979/manifest-in-ignored-on-python-setup-py-install-no-data-files-installed)
- [How do you add additional files to a wheel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347450/how-do-you-add-additional-files-to-a-wheel/49501350#49501350)
- [setuptools: adding additional files outside package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609248/setuptools-adding-additional-files-outside-package)

which suggest different combinations of `data_files`, `package_data`, `include_package_data=True` and/or use of a `Manifest.in` file but still I can't get this working as I would like, so I'm here hoping someone can advise what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html

Comment: thanks, that's helped a lot. I've had to restructure my code a lot to match the structure in your article and it now works. I'm now unpicking it bit by bit to move it back to the structure I want and see where it breaks. One key difference is that my code consists of only a module, not a package. Let's see if I can make it work.

Comment: I see. Basically you should start with the last example (the 5th) you showed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data files (in that case `myjar.jar`) should really be *package data files*, and as such they should be part of a Python package. So having such files in parent directories makes things much more complicated, but probably not impossible. So let's start with a simpler example. I believe something like the following should work...

Project directory structure:

```
MyProject
├ MANIFEST.in
├ mymodule.py
├ setup.py
└ myjars
    ├ __init__.py
    └ myjar.jar
```

`MANIFEST.in`:

```
recursive-include myjars *.jar
```

`setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='MyProject',
    version='1.2.3',
    #
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=['myjars'],
    py_modules=["mymodule"],
)
```

`myjars/__init__.py` might not be strictly necessary, but I believe it's better to have it. And as always, an empty `__init__.py` file is perfectly good enough.

(This assumes the `myjars/myjar.jar` file exists before the *source distribution* `sdist` is built.)

As to dealing with the data files in parent directories, my recommendation would be to simply copy (or symlink) those files before calling `setup.py`, maybe as part of a shell script or anything like that. There are probably ways to do the copy as part of a custom *setuptools* command in `setup.py`, but it's not worth the effort in my opinion, and really it's not part of `setup.py`'s job.

Comment: YES! That did it, thank you SO much. And you're right about the symlink as well of course, so i created that.