# Handle file imports after package installation

Tags: python, package, setuptools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setuptools: package data folder location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519127/setuptools-package-data-folder-location)

I have implemented an application in Python, which I now want to package.

Here is a simplified version of my tree

```
.
├── ivolution
│   ├── data
│   │   └── ui
│   │       ├── AboutIvolutionDialog.glade
│   │       └── IvolutionWindow.glade
│   ├── Face.py
│   ├── gui
│   │   ├── AboutDialog.py
│   │   ├── IvolutionWindow.py
|   |
│   ├── Guy.py
│   ├── training_types.py
|
├── Ivolution.py
├── setup.py
```

The main script to be run is Ivolution.py

My gui (in ivolution/gui) imports glade files.

Inside of my GUI code (IvolutionWindow.py), I have to import my glade file, which I do with a

```
    self.builder.add_from_file("ivolution/data/ui/IvolutionWindow.glade")
```

This works perfectly if I work from the package. But if I install the package with

```
python setup.py install
```

When I run Ivolution.py, the working directory is when the script is run, and not the location of IvolutionWindow.py any more.

So I end up with import errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/Ivolution.py", line 10, in <module>
    my_app = IvolutionWindow.IvolutionWindow("Ivolution")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ivolution/gui/IvolutionWindow.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.builder.add_from_file("ivolution/data/ui/IvolutionWindow.glade")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
gi._glib.GError: Failed to open file 'ivolution/data/ui/IvolutionWindow.glade': No such file or directory
```

My question is, how can I handle my imports correctly ?

I need a variable with my install directory and my local data directory (~/.Ivolution) I guess, but I can't find how to do that efficiently.

Thanks for the help, I couldn't find good resources on the web explaining that. 
Feel free to ask questions, you can learn more about the project [here](https://github.com/jlengrand/FaceMovie/tree/ppa_pythonpackaging).

**EDIT :**

hum, seems like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519127/setuptools-package-data-folder-location) answers half my questions.
I still have to find how to efficiently create a personal folder to save my logs.