# Does pip install work with single module projects?

Tags: python, module, installation, pip, package

I just refactored my [Python project](https://github.com/blokeley/forcelib) to be a single top-level module rather than a package.

However, pip install does not work anymore:  I get an error which says:

```
(forcelib_test) C:\code>pip install git+https://github.com/blokeley/forcelib
Collecting git+https://github.com/blokeley/forcelib
  Cloning https://github.com/blokeley/forcelib to c:\users\tomoak~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-t10zegic-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\forcelib.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\forcelib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\forcelib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info\forcelib.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\forcelib.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\forcelib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    error: package directory 'forcelib' does not exist
```

I'm not trying to install a *package* called forcelib, only a module.  The [setup.py](https://github.com/blokeley/forcelib/blob/master/setup.py) script correctly uses the `py_modules` argument rather than `packages`.

Is it possible to install a single module or do I have to revert to using a package?

Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461603/setting-up-setup-py-for-packaging-of-a-single-py-file-and-a-single-data-file-wi) is about a different problem. They want to install an additional text file. I just want to install the single Python module. In fact, that question implies that what I'm trying to do should work without the error I got

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up setup.py for packaging of a single .py file and a single data file without needing to create any folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461603/setting-up-setup-py-for-packaging-of-a-single-py-file-and-a-single-data-file-wi)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The referenced question is about how to install _additional supporting_ files. Indeed, that question implies that installing a single Python module should work. Is it possible to install just a Python module, not a package?  I updated my question to address the potential duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIP install "error: package directory 'X' does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336150/pip-install-error-package-directory-x-does-not-exist)

Comment: On reading the docs again, I think I need to say `py_modules=['forcelib']` not forcelib.py.    I'll test later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use

```
 py_modules=['forcelib']
```

Rather than what I had which was

```
py_modules=['forcelib.py']
```