# How to add package data recursively in Python setup.py?

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I have a new library that has to include a lot of subfolders of small datafiles, and I'm trying to add them as package data.  Imagine I have my library as so:

```
 library
    - foo.py
    - bar.py
 data
   subfolderA
      subfolderA1
      subfolderA2
   subfolderB
      subfolderB1 
      ...
```

I want to add all of the data in all of the subfolders through `setup.py`, but it seems like I manually have to go into every single subfolder (there are 100 or so) and add an `__init__.py` file.  Furthermore, will `setup.py` find these files recursively, or do I need to manually add all of these in `setup.py` like:

```
package_data={
  'mypackage.data.folderA': ['*'],
  'mypackage.data.folderA.subfolderA1': ['*'],
  'mypackage.data.folderA.subfolderA2': ['*']
   },
```

I can do this with a script, but seems like a super pain.  How can I achieve this in `setup.py`?

PS, the hierarchy of these folders is important because this is a database of material files and we want the file tree to be preserved when we present them in a GUI to the user, so it would be to our advantage to keep this file structure intact.

Comment: You want to compile all of those files as .exe?

Comment: No, just want them accessible in program. If they are installed this way, I can access them in a path called `data_dir`:

    pkg_dir = op.abspath(op.dirname(__file__))
    data_dir = op.join(pkg_dir, 'data')

Then I could do in my program

    open('data_dir/somedatafile', 'r')

Where data_dir will refer to wherever they were installed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Use [Setuptools](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#setuptools) instead of distutils.
2. Use [data files](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#data-files) instead of package data.  These do not require `__init__.py`.
3. Generate the lists of files and directories using standard Python code, instead of writing it literally:

   ```
   data_files = []
   directories = glob.glob('data/subfolder?/subfolder??/')
   for directory in directories:
       files = glob.glob(directory+'*')
       data_files.append((directory, files))
   # then pass data_files to setup()
   ```

Comment: This answer clarifies the difference between data files and package files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519127/setuptools-package-data-folder-location

Answer (score 59):

The problem with the `glob` answer is that it only does so much. I.e. it's not fully recursive. The problem with the `copy_tree` answer is that the files that are copied will be left behind on an uninstall.

The proper solution is a recursive one which will let you set the `package_data` parameter in the setup call.

I've written this small method to do this:

```
import os

def package_files(directory):
    paths = []
    for (path, directories, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            paths.append(os.path.join('..', path, filename))
    return paths

extra_files = package_files('path_to/extra_files_dir')

setup(
    ...
    packages = ['package_name'],
    package_data={'': extra_files},
    ....
)
```

You'll notice that when you do a `pip uninstall package_name`, that you'll see your additional files being listed (as tracked with the package).

Comment: Instead of `paths.append('../' + os.path.join(path, filename))` do `paths.append(os.path.join('..', path, filename))`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks. Editted my answer. I've been using `os.path.join` wrong all this time. I didn't realize it took a variable number of parameters.

Comment: Thanks, super useful. Worth noting that to get this working I had to include the path to the directory that the `setup.py` file was in by adding `directory = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + str(pathlib.Path(directory))` as the first line in the `package_files(directory)` method.

Comment: Docs say to always use forward slash, not os.path.join; see https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files

Answer (score 16):

To add all the subfolders using `package_data` in `setup.py`:
add the number of `*` entries based on you subdirectory structure

```
package_data={
  'mypackage.data.folderA': ['*','*/*','*/*/*'],
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use glob to select all subfolders in your `setup.py`:

```
...
packages=['your_package'],
package_data={'your_package': ['data/**/*']},
...
```

Comment: recursive globs are not supported by setuptools according to [pypa/setuptools#1806](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1806).

Comment: Interestingly, `package_data={'': ['**/*.yml']}` works to pick up all `.yml` files recursively across my whole project folder. Not an ideal solution, of course. But worth noting.

Comment: Seems like `**/*` is supported now as of Python 3.11 :)

Comment: Seems like this is even better than my approach of doing `package_data={"your_package.data": ["**/*"]}` because it doesn't require an `__init__.py` at all!

Answer (score 8):

##### Update

According to the [change log](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#changes-13) `setuptools` now supports recursive globs, using `**`, in `package_data` (as of `v62.3.0`, released May 2022).

##### Original answer

@gbonetti's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55432314), using a recursive glob pattern, i.e. `**`, would be perfect.

However, as commented by @daniel-himmelstein, that [does not work yet](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1806) in setuptools `package_data`.

So, for the time being, I like to use the following workaround, based on `pathlib`'s [Path.glob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob):

```
def glob_fix(package_name, glob):
    # this assumes setup.py lives in the folder that contains the package
    package_path = Path(f'./{package_name}').resolve()
    return [str(path.relative_to(package_path)) 
            for path in package_path.glob(glob)]
```

This returns a list of path strings relative to the package path, as [required](https://docs.python.org/3.8/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data).

Here's one way to use this:

```
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    package_data={'my_package': [*glob_fix('my_package', 'my_data_dir/**/*'), 
                                 'my_other_dir/some.file', ...], ...},
    ...
)
```

The `glob_fix()` can be removed as soon as setuptools supports `**` in `package_data`.

Comment: Seems like `**/*` is supported now as of Python 3.11 :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have any problem with getting your setup.py code dirty use `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree`.
The whole problem is how to exclude files from it.
Heres some the code:

```
import os.path
from distutils import dir_util
from distutils import sysconfig
from distutils.core import setup

__packagename__ = 'x' 
setup(
    name = __packagename__,
    packages = [__packagename__],
)

destination_path = sysconfig.get_python_lib()
package_path = os.path.join(destination_path, __packagename__)

dir_util.copy_tree(__packagename__, package_path, update=1, preserve_mode=0)
```

**Some Notes**:

This code recursively copy the source code into the destination path.

You can just use the same `setup(...)` but use `copy_tree()` to extend the directory you want into the path of installation.

The default paths of distutil installation can be found in it's [API](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html).

More information about copy_tree() module of distutils can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.dir_util).

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest a little code to add data_files in setup():

```
data_files = []

start_point = os.path.join(__pkgname__, 'static')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_point):
    root_files = [os.path.join(root, i) for i in files]
    data_files.append((root, root_files))

start_point = os.path.join(__pkgname__, 'templates')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_point):
    root_files = [os.path.join(root, i) for i in files]
    data_files.append((root, root_files))

setup(
    name = __pkgname__,
    description = __description__,
    version = __version__,
    long_description = README,
    ...
    data_files = data_files,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can do this with a script, but seems like a super pain. How can I achieve this in setup.py?

Here is a reusable, simple way:

Add the following function in your `setup.py`, and call it as per the Usage instructions. This is essentially the generic version of the accepted answer.

```
def find_package_data(specs):
    """recursively find package data as per the folders given

    Usage:
        # in setup.py
        setup(...
              include_package_data=True,
              package_data=find_package_data({
                 'package': ('resources', 'static')
              }))

    Args:
        specs (dict): package => list of folder names to include files from

    Returns:
        dict of list of file names
    """
    return {
        package: list(''.join(n.split('/', 1)[1:]) for n in
                      flatten(glob('{}/{}/**/*'.format(package, f), recursive=True) for f in folders))
        for package, folders in specs.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw my solution in here in case anyone is looking for a clean way to include their compiled sphinx docs as `data_files`.

`setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup
import pathlib
import os

here = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

# Get documentation files from the docs/build/html directory
documentation = [doc.relative_to(here) for doc in here.glob("docs/build/html/**/*") if pathlib.Path.is_file(doc)]
data_docs = {}
for doc in documentation:
    doc_path = os.path.join("your_top_data_dir", "docs")
    path_parts = doc.parts[3:-1]  # remove "docs/build/html", ignore filename
    if path_parts:
        doc_path = os.path.join(doc_path, *path_parts)
    # create all appropriate subfolders and append relative doc path
    data_docs.setdefault(doc_path, []).append(str(doc))

setup(
    ...
    include_package_data=True,
    # <sys.prefix>/your_top_data_dir
    data_files=[("your_top_data_dir", ["data/test-credentials.json"]), *list(data_docs.items())]
)
```

With the above solution, once you install your package you'll have all the compiled documentation available at `os.path.join(sys.prefix, "your_top_data_dir", "docs")`. So, if you wanted to serve the now-static docs using nginx you could add the following to your nginx file:

```
location /docs {
    # handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
    alias /www/your_app_name/venv/your_top_data_dir/docs;
    expires 30d;
}
```

Once you've done that, you should be able to visit `{your-domain.com}/docs` and see your Sphinx documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add custom code to iterate through the directory contents, you can use `pbr` library, which extends `setuptools`. See here for documentation on how to use it to copy an entire directory, preserving the directory structure:

https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/user/using.html#files

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30770723)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function to return  all files and its paths , you can use the following

```
def sherinfind():
    # Add all folders contain files or other sub directories 
    pathlist=['templates/','scripts/']
    data={}        
    for path in pathlist:
        for root,d_names,f_names in os.walk(path,topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False):
            data[root]=list()
            for f in f_names:
                data[root].append(os.path.join(root, f))                
    
    fn=[(k,v) for k,v in data.items()]    
    return fn
```

Now change the data_files in setup() as follows,

```
data_files=sherinfind()
```

Answer (score -1):

[`find_packages`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#finding-simple-packages) discovers the packages recursively:

```py
setup(
    # [...]
    packages=find_packages(),
    # [...]
)
```

But this requires a `__init__.py`.