# Installing a full directory of data files

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to build a package for my project, using `setup.py` and setuptools. A general search has suggested that data files should be placed under my python package.
For instance, `project/src/package/data`.

But my situation is more in line with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519127/setuptools-package-data-folder-location).

My project consists on a Python console application and a HTML interactive application. Right now (before `setup.py`), I have the console application copy the HTML files to a specific directory with a special command. I'm following this directory structure in source control.

```
project
|-+ console
|   |-+ package
|       |-- __init__.py, etc.
|-+ viz
    |-+ css
    |-+ js
    |-- index.html
```

I'm not sure how this behaviour can be replicated with `setup.py` and egg files.

1. How can I make sure that `viz` will be packaged? The `package_data` option seems to be relative to a package (implying that `viz` should be placed under a package).

   So, `package_data = {'': ['viz/*']}` is not what I am looking for.
2. How is the extraction done?
   Should I use `pkg_resources.resource_filename` to get `viz` into the cache, and then `shutil` to copy the files to the intended location? Is there a more practical alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I considered changing the whole structure and turning `viz` into a package, moving the code that installs it there as well. The result would be like so.

```
project
|-- setup.py
|-+ top-level-package
    |-- __init__.py
    |-+ console
    |   |-- __init__.py, etc.
    |-+ viz
        |-+ css
        |-+ js
        |-- index.html
        |-- __init__.py
```

While this would have worked, I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693250) that actually works for my original purpose. `setup.py` has to recursively copy the files as `package_data` (and the relative paths work with `..`).

```
def package_files(directory):
    paths = []
    for (path, directories, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            paths.append(os.path.join("..", path, filename))
    return paths

extra_files = package_files("viz") # this is relative to the project root

setup(
    ...,
    package_data    = {"mypackage": extra_files}
)
```

I just collapsed the original `console` and `package` into one, so the Python package sits directly under the project root. This is my final structure.

```
project
|-- setup.py
|-+ package
|   |-- __init__.py, etc.
|   |-+ private
|       |-- ...
|-+ viz
    |-+ css
    |-+ js
    |-- index.html
```