# Glob for files in and below directory

Tags: python, glob

I know I can get the immediate contents of a directory with `glob.glob("dir/*")`. I can also get all of the contents of the subdirectories recusively with something like `glob.glob("dir/**/*")`, but this will not contain the direct contents of `dir/`. Is there any glob pattern that will give me the union of the two; everything inside of `dir/`, recursively?

Edit:
In case I am [XY probleming](http://xyproblem.info/) too hard here, I am working on a `setup.py` script and want to include an entire directory as `package_data`. I am currently doing `package_data=["resources/*", "resources/**/*"]`, but that seems a bit strange to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `glob` pattern `dir/**/*` is fine to match the files under the `dir` directory and subdirectories recursively; you need the `recursive=True` named argument to be passed in:

```
glob.glob('dir/**/*', recursive=True)
```

The issue is, without `recursive=True`, `glob` will treat the `**` (recursive glob) pattern as a usual `*` (zero or more characters) and will match any files under `dir/<subdir>/`. When you pass the paramter, `**` is treated specially i.e. as a recursive glob pattern.

---

Also, if your purpose is to just iterate over the files, it's better to use `iglob` to get an iterator instead of a list:

```
glob.iglob('dir/**/*', recursive=True)
```

Comment: Interesting! The `recursive=True` argument indeed pulls in the contents of `dir/`, but it's behavior seems strange for the `dir/**/*` case specifically. `glob("dir/**", recursive=True)` seems the most natural (and also works). Either way, this is being used in a `setup.py` to specify `package_data`, so I cannot exactly pass the `recursive` argument.

Comment: @youngmit What's your eventual plan? What files you want? Under `dir` and some subdirs (what are their names)?

Comment: I have a directory called `resources/`. I want its entire contents. Right now I'm doing `package_data=["resources/*", "resources/**/*"]`, but that seems unnatural

Comment: @youngmit Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693250 Put your recursive `glob` inside `package_files` func.