# How do I package non-code data with python setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a python project with the below structure

```
my-project
   venv
   tests
   setup.py
   abc
      __init__.py
      my_pckg
         __init__.py
         foo.py
      static
         data_0.txt
         sub_dir1
             data_1.yaml
         sub_dir2
             data_2.csv
             another file with space in name.pdf
```

Suppose in `abc/foo.py` I have

```
#abc/foo.py
import os
import yaml
with open(os.path.join("abc", "static", "sub_dir1", "data_1.yaml"), "r") as f:
  content= yaml.safe_load(stream)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(content)
```

Method1: It works as I expect If I open python console in `my-project` directory

```
from abc.my_pckg.foo import content
...
```

Method2: it also works as I expect if I run

```
python abc/foo.py
```

Method3: Now I want to package the code using setup.py file as below

```
import setuptools
import os


def package_files(directory):
    paths = []
    for (path, directories, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            paths.append(os.path.join('..', path, filename))
    return paths


extra_files = package_files('abc/static')

setuptools.setup(
    name="some-name",
    version="0.1.0",
    package_dir={"abc": "abc"},
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={'': extra_files},
    packages=[
        "abc",
        "bma.my_pckg",
    ],
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    install_requires=[],
)
```

I then generate whl file by runnig `python setup.py bdist_wheel --dist=dist`

then move the whl file to where I expect to install and run `pip install ...` to install it

```
new-project
  venv
```

However, when I try to it I get this error

```
  File "abs-path-to-new-poject\venv\lib\site-packages\abc\my_pckg\foo.py", line , in <module>
    with open(os.path.join("abc", "static", "sub_dir1", "data_1.txt"), "r") as f:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc\\static\\data_1.yaml'\
```

How should I fix that? how should I package static data with python?

I want to be able to use the three methods above to run the code

Note: After installation, I have all the file under `venv/Lib/site_packages/static`
The problem is the code I have in `foo.py`

And how do I deal with `another file with space in name.pdf` ?

Note: I am using the method suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693250/11065874

Further read:

- should I use pkg_resources? https://kiwidamien.github.io/making-a-python-package-vi-including-data-files.html
- should I use import_lib? how? https://dev.to/bowmanjd/easily-load-non-python-data-files-from-a-python-package-2e8g

Comment: I won´t  close as "duplicate" because you made some research there - but please check: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1612733 - newer answers there reflect ways that may work, including my answer from ~2019: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57932258/108205

Comment: what should I do? remove `package_data={'': extra_files},` ? I did that and I had the same problem. static dir was not even showing under site_packages/lib

Comment: @jsbueno
I have all the file under `venv/Lib/site_packages/static`
The problem is the code I have in `foo.py`

Comment: Check [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58941536/674039)

Comment: @wim I was just reading that. There is a difference for me. I need to get the parent from `importlib.resources` . how to do that?
from within `my_pckg/foo.py` I want to read files inside `static` sub directories

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing the code to

```
#abc/foo.py
import os
import yaml


_path = os.path.join(Path(__file__).parent.parent, "static", "sub_dir1", "data_1.yaml")

with open(_path, "r") as stream:
    content= yaml.safe_load(stream)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(content)
```

Comment: I t will be more consistent safer if you call the `resolve()` method of Path, as in  `Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`. Also, no need to user the cumbersome `os.path.join`  call if you are already using pathlib: Path objects can be combined using the `/ ` operator. 
All in all you can write: `_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / "static" /  "sub_dir1" / "data_1.yaml"`