# "pip install wheelpackagename" copying few files to specified location (package is in local pypi server)

Tags: python, installation, pip, python-wheel, file-location

When I do "pip install wheel-package-name" I want few of files inside package go to specified folder location and few other files to some other specified location. package is in local PyPI server.
I have tried many ways not getting options for this.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: In my package i have few tcl files which should be placed in tcl/lib folder and other python files should go to site-packges

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-structure the packaging configuration. So you might have to expand your wheel, tarball or whatever you're working with (wheel is just a compressed file too) and re-do the packaging so you can send the files to the folders you want. 
Take a look here:
[setuptools: package data folder location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519127/setuptools-package-data-folder-location)

Comment: [ setuptools: package data folder location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519127/setuptools-package-data-folder-location) for wheel package we cant give absolute path for data_files so any other solutions ?  actually In my package i have few tcl files which should be placed in tcl/lib folder and other python files should go to site-packges ..

Comment: You could write a hook to setup.py to do that but it would be a hack rather than a clean solution. I would use setuptools to install everything you need directly into site packages and then another installable option on the lines of a .deb or a make install routine. You can read more about that here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install

Comment: If you use a hack (a script to do this) when you uninstall/upgrade your package, you might run into issues finding the files you spread around your machine.

Comment: can we write hook to setup.py for wheel package. since wheel package dont have setup file inside.