# How to call a function using relative path from other place?

Tags: python

I an writing a Python package. The index like bellow

```
main.py
pkg
|--utils.py
|--files
   |--1.txt
   |--2.txt
```

I write a function to load the file `1.txt` in the `utils.py` using relative path. And it works in the `utils.py`, but fail when I call the function in the `main.py`.

I konw the reason is the relative path has changed. I want to know how to solve it with not change the relative path.

Another problems is how to add the file to the python package when upload to the pipy.

Comment: I find a similiar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519127/setuptools-package-data-folder-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this is by assigning `files/*` as `package_data` and using `pkg_resources.resource_filename`. In your `setup.py`, assuming your package is named "pkg", add the following inside of `setup()`:

```
package_data={'pkg': ['files/*']}
```

Then to use:

```
import pkg_resources
filepath = pkg_resources.resource_filename('pkg', '1.txt')
```